# function PDO return nothing?

Tags: php, pdo

I use PDO for my project, so i don't know why my function return nothing...

```
function getuser($username) {
    require 'database.php';
    $rep = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM membre where login =:user");
    $rep =$bdd->execute(
        array(
            'user'=>$username
            ));

        while($row = $rep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            //$userid = $row->id;
            //$usermail = $row->email;
            echo $row->id;
        }
}
```

and usage:

```
$uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
echo $uname;
//result: kate
echo getuser($uname);
//result:
```

I don't know Why it's not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error. Code should be:

```
$rep = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM membre where login =:user");
$rep->execute(
    array(
        'user'=>$username
        ));
```

Basically, `$rep` is a `statement`. You `prepare()` a statement and then execute it. Right now you run execute on the wrong object.